Exchange 2019 On-Premise OWA/ECP/Autodiscover Issues
I have lurked here and over at StackExchange (Imagine my surprise to find out they are the same group, just different), and have used questions and answers for years until now when I've hit a roadblock that is just kicking my tail. So, after fighting with the site for over an hour I originally posted this on StackExchange as I had seen numerous topics and conversations regarding MS Exchange issues, but it was pointed out that it should be here and that StackExchange is only for "programming" questions. So I deleted that and moved it here. I still say that if you're only going to have programming questions then get rid of all non-programming questions on that part of the site. I only posted it there as I had seen many other posts, and used those posts many times.
In fact, the logo next to the search bar at the top still shows "StackExchange," and while I think the branding of the site is confusing, that is why I thought StackExchange was where it needed to go. Yes, I was upset after fighting to post for over an hour, and yes there were triads about the experience; however, maybe adding a "this might not be a coding" notification with an option to redirect to ServerFault or meta or whatever the other options are would also be helpful. So, I deleted that question and am reposting it here.
On to the issue at hand ...
Over the past month or so we have been dealing with OWA and ECP access being inconsistently responsive and super, super slow. One minute they are loading in 1-2 seconds on login, the next it is taking 5 minutes to login, and another 2 minutes to bring up the first mail item. And this goes back and forth seemingly randomly. Also, when running commands in the EMS I am getting some "THe I/O operation has been aborted becuase of either a thread exit or an application request. + FullyQualifiedErrorId: JobFailure
Full disclosure I run a total of (3) different deployments: 2 are single domain (1 a Server 2019 environment and 1 a Server 2022) and 1 is a forest / multi-domain (All Server 2019 environment). All of these environments are running as virtual machines on Proxmox Virtual Environments. I am having an issue with the Server 2022, single domain, on-premise exchange deployments, but not the others.
Here is current VM hardware setup (Please note: Site A & Site B are connected through a VPN):
Site A (configured as "Site A" in AD Sites and Services with subnet 10.2.0.0/16)

DC01  (Windows Server 2022)

Virtual Machine

4 Processors (2 sockets, 4 cores per)
8 GiB Memory


Nic 1  - 10.2.0.11 (intINet)

DNS 1 = 10.1.0.11
DNS 2 = 127.0.0.1




EXCH01 (Windows Server 2022 w/Exchange 2019 CU14)

Virtual Machine

16 Processors (2 sockets, 8 cores per)
164 GiB Memory


Nic 1 - 10.2.0.13 (intINet)

Route 10.1.0.0 && 10.2.0.0 through 10.2.0.1
DNS 1 = 10.1.0.11 (DC02)
DNS 2 = 10.2.0.11 (DC01)


Nic 2 - public_ip_address (extINet)

DNS 1 = 10.1.0.11 (DC02)
DNS 2 = 10.2.0.11 (DC01)





Site B (configured as "Site B" in AD Sites and Services with subnet 10.1.0.0/16)

DC02 (Windows Server 2022)

Virtual Machine

4 Processors (2 sockets, 4 cores per)
8 GiB Memory


Nic 1  - 10.1.0.11 (intINet)

DNS 1 = 10.2.0.11
DNS 2 = 127.0.0.1





On to what I've tried so far...
The first things I tried was to move the whole instance to a new server. No improvement.
I also verified that DNS is setup correctly (See above)
When I Use the Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer I get the following results:

Exchange ActiveSync (Manual Specify Server Settings) - I get the following error:
Please Note: This test passed earlier with only a "root certificate" ssl issue.

An ActiveSync session is being attempted with the server.

Attempting to send the OPTIONS command to the server - PASS
Attempting the FolderSyncCommand on the Exchange ActiveSynce Session - FAILED

Additional Details: Exchange ActiveSync returned an HTTP 503 response (Service Unavailable).






Exchange ActiveSync (Autodiscover Server Settings) - I get the following error on the CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml check:

Attempting to test potental Autodiscover URL CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml - FAILED (Does not exist on web server)
Attempting to test potential Autodiscover URL https://autodiscover.example.com:443/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml - FAILED (This should pass)
Please Note: When I visit https://autodiscover.example.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml it will sometimes immediately ask for a user/pass and sometimes it takes 30-45 seconds

Attempting to resovlve the hostname - PASS
Testing TCP Port 443 on host - PASS
Testing the SSL certificate - PASS
Attempting to send an Autodiscover POST Request to potential Autodiscover URLs - FAILED

The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer is attempting to retrieve an XML Autodiscover response from URL CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml for user user.name@example.com. The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer failed to obtain an Autodiscover XML response.
Additional Details:
Exception details:
Message: The operation has timed out
Type: System.Net.WebException
Stack trace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
At Microsoft.M365.RCA.Services.RcaHttpRequest.GetResponse()




Attempting to contact the Autodiscover service using the HTTP redirect method - FAILED (HTTP Redirect not configured)
Attempting to contact the Autodiscover service using the DNS SRV redirect method - FAILED (Not Configured)



I also ran the following commands and below the list is the output with redacted domain information:
Commands:

Get-OabVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, URL, auth
Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, URL, auth, MRSProxyEnabled
Get-EcpVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, URL, auth
Get-OwaVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, URL, auth
Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, URL, auth
Get-ClientAccessService | fl Name, OutlookAnywhereEnabled, AutodiscoverServiceInternalUri
Get-ExchangeCertificate | fl FriendlyName, Subject, CertificateDomains, Services, Issuer, not, Status
Get-OutlookAnywhere | fl server, Name, URL, hostname, auth
Get-MapiVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, URL, auth
Get-OrganizationConfig | fl mapi
Get-ClientAccessArray | fl
Get-OutlookProvider
Get-ExchangeServer | fl name, admin, static*

    Creating a new session for implicit remoting of "Get-OabVirtualDirectory" command...

    ( Get-OabVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, *URL*, *auth* )
    Server                        : EXCH01
    Name                          : OAB (Default Web Site)
    InternalUrl                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/OAB
    ExternalUrl                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/OAB
    BasicAuthentication           : False
    WindowsAuthentication         : True
    OAuthAuthentication           : True
    InternalAuthenticationMethods : {WindowsIntegrated, OAuth}
    ExternalAuthenticationMethods : {WindowsIntegrated, OAuth}

    ( Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, *URL*, *auth*, MRSProxyEnabled )
    Server                        : EXCH01
    Name                          : EWS (Default Web Site)
    InternalNLBBypassUrl          :
    InternalUrl                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/ews/exchange.asmx
    ExternalUrl                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/ews/exchange.asmx
    CertificateAuthentication     :
    InternalAuthenticationMethods : {Ntlm, WindowsIntegrated, WSSecurity, OAuth}
    ExternalAuthenticationMethods : {Ntlm, WindowsIntegrated, WSSecurity, OAuth}
    LiveIdNegotiateAuthentication :
    WSSecurityAuthentication      : True
    LiveIdBasicAuthentication     : False
    BasicAuthentication           : False
    DigestAuthentication          : False
    WindowsAuthentication         : True
    OAuthAuthentication           : True
    AdfsAuthentication            : False
    MRSProxyEnabled               : False

    ( Get-EcpVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, *URL*, *auth* )
    Server                        : EXCH01
    Name                          : ecp (Default Web Site)
    InternalUrl                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/ecp
    ExternalUrl                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/ecp
    InternalAuthenticationMethods : {Basic, Fba}
    BasicAuthentication           : True
    WindowsAuthentication         : False
    DigestAuthentication          : False
    FormsAuthentication           : True
    LiveIdAuthentication          : False
    AdfsAuthentication            : False
    OAuthAuthentication           : False
    ExternalAuthenticationMethods : {Fba}

    ( Get-OwaVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, *URL*, *auth* )
    Starting a command on the remote server failed with the following error message : The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
        + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (exch01.example.local:String) [],     PSRemotingTransportException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
        + PSComputerName        : exch01.example.local

The "JobFailure" block segment was actually repeated 10 times.
I was able to remove the "completed commands" and slowly complete the set. Here are those results:
    ( Get-OwaVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, *URL*, *auth* )
    Server                        : EXCH01
    Name                          : owa (Default Web Site)
    Url                           : {}
    InternalSPMySiteHostURL       :
    ExternalSPMySiteHostURL       :
    SetPhotoURL                   :
    Exchange2003Url               :
    FailbackUrl                   :
    InternalUrl                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/owa
    ExternalUrl                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/owa
    ClientAuthCleanupLevel        : High
    InternalAuthenticationMethods : {Basic, Fba}
    BasicAuthentication           : True
    WindowsAuthentication         : False
    DigestAuthentication          : False
    FormsAuthentication           : True
    LiveIdAuthentication          : False
    AdfsAuthentication            : False
    OAuthAuthentication           : False
    ExternalAuthenticationMethods : {Fba}

    ( Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, *URL*, *auth* )
    Server                              : EXCH01
    Name                                : Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync (Default Web Site)
    MobileClientCertificateAuthorityURL :
    InternalUrl                         : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
    ExternalUrl                         : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync
    MobileClientCertificateAuthorityURL :
    BasicAuthEnabled                    : True
    WindowsAuthEnabled                  : False
    ClientCertAuth                      : Ignore
    InternalAuthenticationMethods       : {}
    ExternalAuthenticationMethods       : {}

    ( Get-ClientAccessService | fl Name, OutlookAnywhereEnabled, AutodiscoverServiceInternalUri )
    Name                           : EXCH01
    OutlookAnywhereEnabled         : True
    AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri : https://autodiscover.example.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml

    ( Get-ExchangeCertificate | fl FriendlyName, Subject, CertificateDomains, Services, Issuer, *not*, Status ))
    FriendlyName       : mail.example.com [Certify] - 5/15/2024 3:08:09 PM to 8/13/2024 3:08:08 PM
    Subject            : CN=mail.example.com
    CertificateDomains : {mail.CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS, attachments.example.CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS, autodiscover.CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS, webmail.CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS}
    Services           : IMAP, POP, IIS, SMTP
    Issuer             : CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US
    NotAfter           : 8/13/2024 3:08:08 PM
    NotBefore          : 5/15/2024 3:08:09 PM
    Status             : Valid

    FriendlyName       : Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate
    Subject            : CN=Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate
    CertificateDomains : {}
    Services           : SMTP
    Issuer             : CN=Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate
    NotAfter           : 9/30/2027 5:59:59 PM
    NotBefore          : 10/26/2022 5:59:59 PM
    Status             : Valid

    FriendlyName       : Microsoft Exchange
    Subject            : CN=EXCH01
    CertificateDomains : {EXCH01, EXCH01.CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS}
    Services           : IIS, SMTP
    Issuer             : CN=EXCH01
    NotAfter           : 10/26/2027 5:57:07 PM
    NotBefore          : 10/26/2022 5:57:07 PM
    Status             : Valid

    FriendlyName       : WMSVC-SHA2
    Subject            : CN=WMSvc-SHA2-EXCH01
    CertificateDomains : {WMSvc-SHA2-EXCH01}
    Services           : None
    Issuer             : CN=WMSvc-SHA2-EXCH01
    NotAfter           : 10/23/2032 3:47:25 PM
    NotBefore          : 10/26/2022 3:47:25 PM
    Status             : Valid


    ( Get-OutlookAnywhere | fl server, Name, *URL*, *hostname*, *auth* )
    Server                             : EXCH01
    Name                               : Rpc (Default Web Site)
    XropUrl                            :
    ExternalHostname                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS
    InternalHostname                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS
    ExternalClientAuthenticationMethod : Negotiate
    InternalClientAuthenticationMethod : Ntlm
    IISAuthenticationMethods           : {Basic, Ntlm, Negotiate}

    ( Get-MapiVirtualDirectory | fl server, Name, *URL*, *auth* )
    Server                        : EXCH01
    Name                          : mapi (Default Web Site)
    InternalUrl                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS
    ExternalUrl                   : CORRECT-DOMAIN-REMOVED-FOR-LIMITATIONS
    IISAuthenticationMethods      : {Negotiate}
    InternalAuthenticationMethods : {Negotiate}
    ExternalAuthenticationMethods : {Negotiate}

    ( Get-OrganizationConfig | fl *mapi* )
    MapiHttpEnabled     : True

    ( Get-ClientAccessArray | fl )
    NO RESULTS RETURNED

    ( Get-OutlookProvider )
    Name Server CertPrincipalName TTL
    ---- ------ ----------------- ---
    EXCH                          1
    EXPR                          1
    WEB                           1

    Get-ExchangeServer | fl name, *admin*, static* >>
    Name                            : EXCH01
    AdminDisplayVersion             : Version 15.2 (Build 1544.4)
    StaticDomainControllers         : {}
    StaticGlobalCatalogs            : {}
    StaticConfigDomainController    :
    StaticExcludedDomainControllers : {}

In my "Microsoft Exchange with Database Availability" event logs I am only seeing

"Error" for expiring certificates
"Error" for a watson report
"Warning" for MSExchange ActiveSync that "The Setting LiveIdBasicAuthModule.ApplicationName in the Web.Config file was missing. Using default vlaue of ."
Everything else is "Information"

In my "Administrative Events"  event log I am seeing the above, plus the following:

"Error" Schannel - A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013. The SSPI client processing is SYSTEM.
"Warning"MSExchange Mid-Tier Storage - Active Manager Client already doing query for object 'XXX'on another thread, however this thread didn;t compelte in 100msec.

In my "Server Roles Web Server (IIS)" event log I am seeing the following:

"Warning" WAS - A processing serving application pool 'MSExchangeSyncAppPool'suffered a fatal communications error with the Windows Proess Activation Service. The process id was 'XXXX'. The data field containes the error number.

Today alone there have been 41 of these events (from 12:14 CST 05/29 through 20:44 CST 05/29)
Some people are suggesting this is a DNS issue; however, it can ping the Domain Controllers, and if it were a mismatched DNS issue when I shutdown DC02 it should have solved the issue; however, it has not.
Someone else suggested rebuilding all of the virtual directories; however, the system was slow prior to installing CU14 update... wouldn't the CU14 update rebuilt/reset the virtual directories?
The other (2) exchange environments I have both allow you to login with 1-2 seconds, MAX. Granted they are running Server 2019 CU10 and CU11 (The client has told me not to update either of them, so not much that I can do.
I am open to any suggestions here.
Thank You in Advance!
Update 202040530 @ 1730Hrs CST
Last night (20240529) I wanted to test the DNS issue theory and I disabled the network on the DC02 VM, and left it off. Nothing changed. In fact, it got worse.
Fast-forward to 10 minutes ago (20240530@1720Hrs CST) I was banging my head on the desk and decided to switch them. I re-enabled the network on DC02 and disabled the network on DC01. Lo and behold, within 3 minutes it is now running like it should. Logging in takes 2-3 seconds on OWA and ECP. Connecting through EMS is fast. This is how it should be.
So, this is not an exchange issue, it is a domain controller issue. I will be running a DCDiag on DC01 when I can re-activate the network, and I will post the results below at that time.
UPDATE - DCDIAG RESULTS: 20240530@2140Hrs CST
As I mentioned earlier, here are the results from running dcdiag. Please note I have changed city names and server names. Please Note: there are a series of DFSREvents in the event log. This were when I had either A.) turned off the network adapter on DC02 or, more recently, turned off the network adapter on DC01 to test and discover that the issue is DC01.
Aside from the errors due to the NIC adapters being disabled, I am not seeing anything that would explain why DC01 is causing all manner of problems for exchange, but DC02 is fine.
See this link for dcdiag results: https://pastebin.com/Ckwe5RdF
UPDATE: 20240601@1722Hrs - Diagnosing Requests
I was asked to do some additional diagnosing steps , but I am not able to paste all the information here.
Please see this link for a full rundown:
https://pastebin.com/x6nkBnkM

Good afternoon everyone, I wanted to provide anyone who might run into this issue later an update with the solution to this particular issue.
Someone recommended decommissioning DC01 and starting a DC00 on a separate IP address in the same site as DC01/EXCH01. I did this, and it did work for a short time, but within 36 hours the issue had come back up and it was again taking 3-4 minutes to login, and another 1-2 minutes to view the first email address. So, this was not the answer.
The next thing I did was setup wireshark on DC00, DC01, DC02, and EXCH-01 and watch the traffic as someone attempted to login. During this period it looked like some of the traffic just wasn't making it there, but it was not consistent, and eventually in the logs I would see an ADTopology "information" event that it would loose connection with DC00/DC01.
This made me look into the persistent routes on the Exchange server. Right now there was a persistent route for 10.2.0.0/16 and 10.1.0.0/16 all going through 10.2.0.1. I looked at some of my other deployments and they all had 10.0.0.0/8 persistent routes. So I modified to match, and of course then the Exchange server was not able to ping anything in the 10.1.0.0/16 network.
I was a little baffled and decided to look at the router logs and see what was happening to the traffic going to 10.1.0.0/16. As this was a VPN Site-to-Site link using OpenVPN on our pfsense router I started with the OpenVPN logs. Nothing stood out so I started looking at all of the other logs.
Eventually I wokred my way to the firewall log, and imagine my suprise but there was a lot of traffic being blocked across the LAN network, and when I looked closer it was all from EXCH-01 to DC00 and DC01, specifically port 3268. Why this was being blocked, I do not know; however, it was, and after fixing the previous persistent route issues, restarting the server, and then creating a rule to allow that traffic from EXCH-01 to DC01 everything started to work normally. Login times are down to less than 3 seconds on OWA and ECP both local and using external addresses.
Now, why did the pfSense router's firewall all the sudden decide that SOME of the traffic to port 3268 should be blocked across the lan interface? I have no idea. That is an issue for another time. However, had I not broken the persistent routing, there is no telling how long it would have taken me to figure this issue out.

why did the pfSense router's firewall all the sudden decide Firewall blocked the main GC port? That would be a terrible firewall product.

@GregAskew, that is one of the things I'm researching now. Unfortunately, pfSense was only keeping 500k log files, and only 7 of them before rolling over. I've upped that, and I am also deploying a syslog server, but all the old details are gone. I am going to "un-fix" the issue and delete the rule to see if it replicates the issue. and then I can pull logs.

@GregAskew I did not get the notice on this; however, the issue was actually due to the "public" IP address was being sent to the AD DNS Servers. The server has one card for local net access and one for direct internet access. The second adapter was updating DNS. What happened is that when the Exchange Server connected to the DC Server, but the DC server responded to the public IP. The constant requests is what caused the firewall to flag and block it. I went into the adapter and unchecked the "update DNS with IP" checkbox and reset the rules and all issues were resolved.
